# Do hidden Markov models contain Markov chains?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Is it correct to say that the Hidden State Sequence in a Hidden Markov Model is a Markov Chain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely a Markov chain because the observed variables define the transition probabilities from every *latent variable configuration* to every other.  (That is, they yield an $n \times n$ matrix of probabilities where $n$ is the number of latent variable configurations.)

Usually you can say more about the Markov chain:

If you're talking about Boltzmann machines, for example, then the Markov chain you get from iterating the variables is *time-homogenous* since time doesn't matter.  This would also be true in a regular Markov model if you were to hold the observed nodes fixed.

For Boltzmann machines, you also have *ergodicity* since all states are positive recurrent (for finite weights).  You can often have the same property for a Markov model.

If you have an ergodic, time-homogenous Markov chain, then the network converges to a steady state distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, A hidden Markov model is a bivariate stochastic process
                 $\{(X_t,Y_t)\}_{t\geq0}$, defined on a product space $(\mathsf{X}
                 \times \mathsf{Y},\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y})$, where
                 $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a Markov chain taking
                 values in $\mathsf{X}$ and $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq0}$, defined on some state
                 space $\mathsf{Y}$, is a sequence of observable random
                 variables conditional on $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$.